# Listview shows only first element

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I have an ListView element in my layout,with other views:

```
 ...  
 <ListView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/listView1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:visibility="gone" android:></ListView>
 ...
```

when the Activity is created I fill the Listview with an Array of values:

```
  ListView list_ultime_ricette=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
  list_ultime_ricette.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);
  list_ultime_ricette.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Home.this, R.layout.list_item, ricette_name));
```

And this is list_item.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:textSize="16dp" >
```

But when I try the whole, I see only the first element of my array, does anyone know why?

Comment: Can you include the code where you populate the ricette_name array?

Comment: the array is populated with something like 15 items,that is for sure

Comment: Post the code either way, we cannot help if you exclude key parts such as when you populate the array. Seeing as how your question asks why you only see one element in an array, it's important that you post the code that creates the array, not just the code that displays it.

Answer (score 4):

Don't put ListView inside of a ScrollView :)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing list_item.xml to be this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="10dp"
android:textSize="16dp" >
```

Only change is settings layout_height to "wrap_content" instead of "fill_parent".

Answer (score 1):

Don't put Listview inside a ScrollView

Comment: This looks *extremely* similar to Muhammad's answer. What's the deal?

Comment: Do not copy answers instead you should vote up and not to copy